# wrong type argument: stringp, nil

Tags: emacs, elisp

Before now I've just been cutting and pasting code into my .emacs file, but then I decided to add some maven functionality to emacs.  Now, I don't see how I was able to mess this up, but last night I kept getting the error I put in the title when I run M-x jarl-mvn-exec.  I slept on it, and came back the next day but I'm still not getting anywhere.

```
(defun jarl-get-pom ()
  (concat (locate-dominating-file 
       (buffer-file-name 
        (current-buffer))
       "pom.xml")
      "pom.xml"))

(defun jarl-visit-pom ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file (jarl-get-pom)))

(defun jarl-mvn-exec ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "maven"))
  (start-process-shell-command "mvn-exec" "maven" "mvn" "-f" (jarl-get-pom) "compile")
  (start-process-shell-command "mvn-exec" "maven" "mvn" "-f" (jarl-get-pom) "exec:exec"))
```

Comment: Might be worth to mention that the error message "wrong type argument: stringp, nil" means that Emacs _expected_ a string but got a `nil` instead.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You'll need to provide more information to be sure.  Try setting

```
(setq debug-on-error t)
```

which will give you a stack trace showing what function is complaining about the string being nil.

My guess is that `buffer-file-name` is returning nil, and that's where the problem lies (not all buffers have file names).  Check out the [debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Debugging.html) section of [An Introduction To Programming in Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/), or the [debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging) section of the Emacs Lisp manual.

Comment: My intention was to get the pom above the file for the current buffer in emacs, but I switched the buffer to a different one(one with no file) to see the results of my maven commands.

Comment: Good answer. The link to the debugging section of An Introduction To Programming in Emacs Lisp is https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Debugging.html#Debugging

Answer (score 16):

The secret to finding a problem in your init file is not a secret: **binary search**.

Use `comment-region` to comment out half your init file, then 3/4, 7/8,... It is *very* quick to identify the problem. `comment-region` also uncomments: `C-h f comment-region RET`.

Comment: Tho, in this instance, he needs to debug basically a "single chunk" of code, and he already knows which chunk it is, so there's really not much to be gained from binary search (which otherwise indeed usually works well for `~/.emacs` by virtue of it being mostly a sequence of independent instructions).