# 'End of file during parsing' when attempting to exit Emacs

Tags: emacs

When I attempt to kill Emacs (with `save-buffers-kill-terminal`) I get the error

```
End of file during parsing
```

Looking at the `*Messages*` buffer, I see:

```
progn: End of file during parsing
```

No `*Backtrace*` buffer shows up, even with `debug-on-error` set to `t`.

How do I figure out what is going on?

Comment: How are you invoking `save-buffers-kill-terminal`? Are you typing `M-x save-buffers-kill-terminal`, or are you typing `C-x C-c`, or something else? Also, what major and minor modes do you have enabled?

Comment: Typing C-x C-c.  I have a rather large emacs file with a lot of external packages so a way to narrow down which is the poblem would be good.

Comment: Can you try `C-h k C-x C-c` to make sure that `save-buffers-kill-terminal` is actually the function being invoked?

Comment: It sounds rather like unbalanced parens in the library for an autoloaded function listed in `kill-emacs-hook` or `kill-emacs-query-functions`, or something similar. `M-x check-parens` is extremely useful for showing where the problem is, but you need to know which elisp file to run it in.

Answer (score 2):

[Recursively bisect your init file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7129300/729907) to find which part of it leads to the problem.

Yes, this means restarting and quitting Emacs multiple times, but this is a **binary search**, so it is in fact very fast, even if it is essentially thoughtless.  Importantly, it is systematic, which guessing is typically not.

Likewise, if you find that the problem comes from some library that you load: recursively bisect it to find the problem in it.

And as @phils said, `check-parens` is also your friend.