# emacs can't turn on minor-mode automatically

Tags: emacs, minor-mode

I want irony-mode be turned on automatically in c-mode. But I have tried two ways, both fail. Can someone teach me? I don't like to type `M-x irony-mode` always.

1:

```
(require 'irony)
(defun my:irony-init ()
  (irony-mode 1))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:irony-init)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:irony-init)
```

**OR** 2:

```
(require 'irony)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
```

I find not only `irony-mode`, but also `ggtags` and `flycheck` can't load through `add-hook`. I have `（add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode）`, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me? My `.emacs.d` has uploaded to `github：`https://github.com/cfampc/emacs.d。 My `irony-mode` is configured in `.emacs.d/custom/c-settings.el` and `flycheck` `ggtags` is in `.emacs.d//custom/edit-settings.el`. Before I can have `ggtags-mode` auto-load in C. Now, If I add `(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'irony-mode)` after `(load ...)` all of my config file, it does work. But if I add it in `.emacs.d/custom/c-settings.el` , It doesn't work. why?

Comment: Have you verified whether the mode is active, but may not be doing what you expect?  `M-x describe-mode` to see what modes are active in the buffer.  The Github readme.md webpage for the library at issue has some additional *Configuration* setup beyond just a major-mode-hook:  https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode

Comment: If I use `M-x irony-mode`, it can work normally. I think it's because my minor can't be loaded. I have typed `(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'fly-check-mode)`, but `flycheck` can't be loaded automatically in `C-mode`, also.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine, so you should [recursively bisect your config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7129300/324105) to find the source of the problem.

Comment: It's a typo, sorry. I mean that I use either of two, I can't succeed. I use emacs 24.5. For your "1" and "2", I don't use `irony-mode`, It's a typo.